# What kind of brackets should I use in try statements in Java?

Tags: java, try-catch

I have been reading in the Oracle Java Documentation a bit and noticed that they use '(' brackets in their try-Statements, but pretty much everyone else only uses '{'.

Are there different cases where one should be preferred over the other or is there no difference between them? I couldn't find an answer in the Java API so I thought why not ask here...

Comment: They are used in different places. You can't just exchange one for the other, that will cause a compile time error.

Comment: try statement: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html. try-with-resources statement: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: I think you might be mis-reading the code you're looking at; there is a single syntax for try-catch (unless you count multi-catch as "different" I suppose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different statements in Java: `try` and `try-with-resources`. They do related but different things. You use `{}` with `try` and `()` and `{}` with `try-with-resources`. `try-with-resources` makes it *dramatically* easier to use resources that support the `AutoCloseable` interface, as it handles closing resources for you (regardless of how control left the block — whether it completed normally or threw an exception).

Sample `try` statement:

```
try {
    // Do something that may throw an exception
}
catch (RelevantExceptionType e) {
    // Do something about it
}
finally {
    // This runs whether an exception happened or not
}
```

The `try` can have zero or more `catch` blocks and zero or one `finally` block (and must have at least one `catch` or `finally`, it can't be completely on its own).

More in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html).

Sample `try-with-resources`:

```
try (
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("some file")
    ) {
}
catch (RelevantExceptionType e) {
    // Do something about it
}
finally {
    // This runs regardless of whether there was an exception
}
```

The `try-with-resources` can have zero or more `catch` blocks and zero or one `finally` blocks, and doesn't *have* to have either (it *can* be completely on its own).

More in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).